# ffmpeg select highest quality video track and audio track in specific language from m3u8

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a bunch of .m3u8 files that contain video tracks in different resolutions and bitrates, and audio tracks in different laguages.
I want to select the highest quality video stream and if available the audio track in a specified language.

I know how to select the audio track, currently I use

```
-map 0:m:language:en?
```

like this

```
ffmpeg -re -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i .\some_file.m3u8 -codec:a aac -c:v copy -f flv -map 0:m:language:en? rtmp://foo.com:1935/live/xyz
```

With that I only stream audio if the specified audio language is available, or audio and video in the default configuration if it's not.

I want to stream the best video track (the one ffmpeg picks by default) in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, this needs chained ffmpeg commands,

`ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist file,http,https,tcp,tls -i .\some_file.m3u8 -c copy -map 0:v -map 0:m:language:en? -f mpegts - | ffmpeg -re -f mpegts -i - -c:v copy -c:a aac -f flv rtmp://foo.com:1935/live/xyz`

Comment: the first part works, it copies all video tracks and only the correct audio track, but the second part runs into an issue.

I get the error

`Unable to find a suitable output format for 'rtmp://foo.com:1935/live/xyz'
rtmp://foo.com:1935/live/xyz: Invalid argument`

Comment: I figured it out, I need to use `-f flv` instead of `-f mpegts` in the second part.

I also need to turn on experimental codecs for aac with `-strict -2 ` for some reason.
The resulting stream stutters quite a bit so I still need to figure that out.

Comment: `-strict -2` hasn't been needed for  AAC since 2016. Your build is very old.